# Error in function call from inside return along with jsx

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a recursive call for parse directories. My code fails to compile.
Problem in call done as `{getSubMenus( dir[objKey].subDir )}` inside the second return

Error: 
    ')' expected.

```
function getSubMenus(dir) {
    if (Object.entries(dir).length === 0 && dir.constructor === Object) 
        return;

    return (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(dir).map((objKey,index) => {
                return (
                    <li>
                        <Link to={`/${dir[objKey].url}`} >{objKey}</Link>
                    </li> 
                    {getSubMenus( dir[objKey].subDir )}         
                )                 
            })}   
        </ul>
    )
}

return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Locations</h1>

        {Object.keys(locationMenu).map((objKey,index) => (
            <li>
                <h3><Link to={`/${locationMenu[objKey].url}`}>{objKey}</Link>
                </h3>
                {getSubMenus(locationMenu[objKey].subDir)}
            </li>
        ))}   
    </Layout>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (
  <li><Link to={`/${dir[objKey].url}`} >{objKey}</Link></li> 
  {getSubMenus( dir[objKey].subDir )}         
)
```

Instead of this try to wrap content returned in a Fragment.

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
   <li>
    <Link to={`/${dir[objKey].url}`} >{objKey}</Link>
   </li> 
   {getSubMenus( dir[objKey].subDir )} 
  </React.Fragment>        
)
```

Comment: please mark it as answered, if the problem is solved.